# iOS crash due to memory exceeding 50 mb limit error ReplayKit

Tags: ios, replaykit

We are using ReplayKit framework to use the iOS screen recording feature for our app. We are processing the CMSampleBufferRef and doing a conversion into UIImage using VideoToolBox framework. 
After processing a few buffers the extension is crashing due to memory exceeding 50 MB with alert :

"Live Broadcast to **** has stopped due to: (null)"

My question is :

- Is there any better way to convert CMSampleBufferRef to UIImage, since I have used many ways and nothing worked except VideoToolBox.
- In the Extension crash alert which we are receiving, is there any way by which we add some information to the customer about the crash? Because this 'null' alert is very odd for customers.

Comment: Have you found any solution for converting the CMSampleBuffer to UIImage without passing the memory limit?

Comment: @MehmetBaykar I stated using JPEG encoding to resolve the memory issue.

Comment: @useruser7424029
can you give an example or url that shows the way of doing the encoding?

Comment: you need to use libjep for the same, jpeg directly works with yuv buffers so you don't need to convert yuv video buffers. you can look into github for examples how jpeg works with libjpeg.